# How do I create a trigger to insert a value into an ID field that is Max([ID Field])+1 on insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

When I add a new record I want SQL Server to automatically add a fresh ID.

There are already some records which have been migrated over (from Access) and until I finish preparing the server for other required functionality I will be manually migrating further records over (if this affects any possible answers).

What are the simplest ways to implement this.

Comment: Typically, those approaches are **not recommended** since there's a high likelihood that this simplistic system will fail miserably under load - dishing out duplicate values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way would be to make the column an [`IDENTITY` column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx). [Here is an example of how to do this](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1397/add-or-drop-identity-property-for-an-existing-sql-server-column/?utm_source=AaronBertrand) (it's not as simple as `ALTER TABLE`).

Comment: Thanks Aaron, as I'll be using MS Access as a front end anyway.  Think I'll keep control of the Parent IDs there. There are not many Parent IDs (No more than three a day) so won't be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the `Identity` field type.  This will automatically create a value for you using the next available number in the sequence.

Here is an example of how to create an `Identity` column (add a new column) on an existing table

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD IdColumn INT IDENTITY(1,1)
```